# Output like the game description window?

Tags: c++, string, windows

What I want to do is to output the text when there is a certain sentence and give it a specific time interval so that it is output as if typing.
This was handled by using the Sleep() function when printing a string.
However, when the space bar (or any key) is pressed while a sentence is being printed, I want the remaining sentences to be output at once without a time delay.
Because there are people who want to read text quickly.
(I'm making a text-based game.)
And from the next sentence, the string should be output with a time interval back to the original.
So, I wrote the code as below, but if I press the space bar once, all the sentences following it are printed at once without a time interval.
My guess is that once the spacebar is pressed, it works as if the spacebar is pressed continuously after that.
How can I solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool space;
void type(string str)
{
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {//Print until \0 appears
        printf("%c", str[i]);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000) {//When the user presses the spacebar
            space = true;//Turn AABSD into true
        }

        if (space) {//If the space bar is pressed
            Sleep(0);//Print all the letters of a sentence without a break
        }
        else {//If the space bar is not pressed
            Sleep(500);//Print at 0.5 second intervals per character
        }
    }
    space = false;
}

int main(void)
{
    space = false;

    type("Hello, World!\n");
    type("Hello, World!\n");
    type("Hello, World!\n");
    type("Hello, World!\n");
    type("Hello, World!\n");
    type("Hello, World!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the time it takes for you to press and release the space bar, C++ has printed everything already.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `type`, you can loop until you see space being released:

```
void type(string str) {
  ...
  while (space) {
    space = (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000);
    Sleep(10);
  }
}
```

Sleeping for 10 milliseconds at a time [prevents pressing space from overheating your computer](https://xkcd.com/1172/).